# ASP.NET MVC and IIS Express - Change executing directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

Currently I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application that should use an existing framework. I am hosting this ASP.NET MVC app in IIS Express. Some classes of this framework assume that files are relative to the current directory. Right now the assemblies are executed in ***c:\users\MyName\appdata\local\temp\temporary asp.net files\root\3c076611\5261f232\assembly\dl3\d36edef7\e39ad394_8136d101***.
Is it possible to change this directory?

Answer (score 0):

```
var rootLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

now load your file as

```
var filePath  = Path.Combine(rootLocation,"relative path to your assembly");
```

Edit:

if you cannot change framework, then you can change temp directory using web.config, add  `<compilation tempDirectory="C:\Project\Temp\">`, but this will change only "c:\users\MyName\appdata\local\temp\temporary asp.net files\" part, rest of additional folders will still be there

Comment: I know how I can access these files programmatically, but I don't want to change the framework. The framework will work automattically when it's executed in the right location.